# How to use dbus-send to call org.bluez.Adapter1.StartDiscovery?

Tags: dbus, bluez

I am trying to interact with Bluez 5.44 using the [`dbus-send`](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-send.1.html) command line tool. I cannot seem to get it to start discovery properly, although it works fine when I use `bluetoothctl`'s `scan on` and `scan off` commands. I can also start and stop discovery using `d-feet`.

I've tried powering off and on prior to issuing the command, but it doesn't seem to get discovery started.

The command line I'm using is:

```
dbus-send --system --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.bluez \
    /org/bluez/hci0                                                  \
    org.bluez.Adapter1.StartDiscovery
```

What I usually get upon issuing this command is from `dbus-monitor` is that the `Discovering` property is `false`.

For reference, this is what `d-feet` shows.

[image].

What am I doing wrong with this command?

Comment: Had a thought. Something to do with sessions?

Comment: Try with sudo ?

Comment: Try monitoring what `bluetoothctl scan on` does by running `sudo dbus-monitor --system` at the same time as you run `bluetoothctl`. See if it does anything on the bus additional to what you are trying with `dbus-send`.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that dbus-send exits almost immediately. BlueZ keeps track of clients that are requesting discovery (have a D-Bus proxy to the adapter open), and the discovery will stop when no more clients are requesting it.

d-feet and bluetoothctl are long-living processes that keep the org.bluez.Adapter1 proxy to the adapter alive.

I hit the same problem with a glib client I'm working on, and there the solution is to keep the D-Bus proxy object to the adapter alive.

This is probably bad news if you have to stick with dbus-send.